# Finding the maximum value for each column and the corspondace vlaue of a common column

Tags: dataframe, max

I am trying to get the maximum value from each column in a dataframe with their time that they occur.

```
l = [[1,6,2,6,7],[2,66,2,6,8],[3,44,2,44,8],[4,5,35,6,8],[5,3,9,6,95]]
dft = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Time','25','50','75','100'])
max_t = pd.DataFrame()
max_t['Max_f'] = dft.loc[:, ['25','50','75','100']].max(axis=0)
max_t
```

I managed to get the maximum value in each column, however, I could not figure out how to get the time.

Comment: what about `dft.max()`?

Comment: I already used it!

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is your desired (resulting) dta set?

Comment: If you execute the code will get two columns one for the columns names (i.e 25, 50, 75, 100) the other column is the maximum value. I need to add third column for the time which contains the time where the maximum value occurs. for example for 25 the maximum value was 66 and occurs at time =6 (how can I get this 6 and display it)?!

Comment: there is no `time=6` in your data set ;-)

Comment: sorry MaxU, it was my mistake its 2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [48]: dft
Out[48]:
   Time  25  50  75  100
0     1   6   2   6    7
1     2  66   2   6    8
2     3  44   2  44    8
3     4   5  35   6    8
4     5   3   9   6   95

In [49]: dft.set_index('Time').agg(['max','idxmax']).T
Out[49]:
     max  idxmax
25    66       2
50    35       4
75    44       3
100   95       5
```

Comment: Sure. but I got an error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: @SamirAlhejaj, what is your Pandas version? `DataFrame.agg()` was added in Pandas 0.20

Comment: I am using 3.6. any alternative

Comment: sorry its '0.17.1'

Comment: @SamirAlhejaj, 0.17 is pretty old - would you consider upgrading it?

Comment: The upgrade may cause some issues.  I wonder if there is an iterative method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152277/discussion-between-samir-alhejaj-and-maxu).